# Exception is not correctly handling if the model validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, model

This exception not handling this error.

There is no question update template, after question update it will redirect to index page, but when the model validation got error while saving the below message is showing.

```
def update
begin
 programme..
 ......
 Question.save
 flash[:sussess] = "Question created"
 redirect_to :action=>'index'
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
  flash[:error] = "Duplicate question,exception due to the model validation"
  redirect_to :action=>'index'
end
```

[image: This is from update action]

What is the way to correct the exception handling for the following scenerio.

Comment: Posting the full code is important here.

Comment: i already added the exception handling in that update action but its not triggering as an exception.

Comment: @sevenseacat sorry the complete code in that action around 769 lines.

Comment: then you have a lot of refactoring to do.

Comment: @sevenseacat Its actualy a very big system, the refactoring its not possible easily. want to handle it as "rescue" for complete update action code.

Comment: @errakesh  Can you add Exception rescue Exception and check the exception class? I think that ActionView::MissingTemplate is not exception class that are raising these exception even though it is showing exception logs. It happen to my projects also.

Comment: @Sanjiv i tried to use "rescue" and "rescue Exception" but that two are not working,Thanks

Comment: @sevenseacat Its actualy a very big system, the refactoring its not possible easily. want to handle it as "rescue" for complete update action code.

Comment: @sevenseacat The duplicate question will not save because of the model validation, that time this error will occur, then i tried to use the exception for complete "update" action code for this specific error. but its not reach in the recue area .

Comment: @sevenseacat the update action is very lengthy code around 768 lines above and there is lots of question.save in that , so the refactoring and the conditional check including is not possible faster. So the complete "update action code want to wrap inside of the begin..recue--end block.

Comment: @errakesh please stop tagging me :(

Comment: You cannot rescue that error since it is raised *after* your controller action completed. If you didn't call `render` or `redirect` in the action, Rails will do its default rendering, which in your case is the `update` template. You're most likely returning early somewhere in your action, so Rails implicitly renders the `update` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario we need to handle in the bellow manner (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid).
I solved it by adding this rescue to the code.

```
begin
    .....
    .....
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
  flash[:error] = t('flash_notice.qs_duplicate')
  return redirect_to (:back)
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
def update
  if @question.update(question_params)
    redirect_to action: 'index'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Assuming you have errors displaying on your form then just render the edit template.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @sevenseacat I disagree, given his flash message the best way to get the functionality he wants is with validations and rendering the form and displaying the errors.

Comment: @japed the update action is very lengthy code around 768 lines above and there is lots of question.save in that , so the refactoring and the conditional check including is not possible faster. So the complete "update action code want to wrap inside of the begin..recue--end block.